# Printf statement executed after system command

Tags: c, linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have this simple program written and executed on wsl2.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("Current date is : ");
    system("date");
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, the printf statement is getting executed last. So here is the output I am getting.

```
Mon Nov  7 12:00:49 IST 2022
Current date is :
```

Any idea how I can handle the sequence of execution?
My expectation is for printf to execute first.

Comment: Add a call to `fflush` after the first `printf`.  The output of that first `printf` is sitting in the buffer.

Comment: Also, please don't tag C++ for C questions.  Removed.

Comment: The key concept here is `line buffering`. If you end a `printf` format string with `\n` it will likely print immediately. Otherwise it will potentially delay outputting until it does encounter a `\n` like in the second `printf`.

Comment: It is good to note that calling `system` is not typical for C programs. It's fine if some course is teaching you this. But usually you would use some combination of `time`, `localtime` and  `strftime` here.

Comment: @Cheatah Thanks for sharing that piece of information about line buffering. I understand why it's behaving the way it is now.

Comment: @PaulSanders The fflush worked. Thank you. Will accept your answer.

Comment: Hi Joe, it's not really worth an answer, it's been asked a million times before (and I should probably have tracked down a dupe).  Anyway, yw.